# Updating mySQL DB but POST is not returning a value

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm trying to update two fields in an individual record.  However, when I click the "Update" button and the changes are submitted nothing is posted to the `assigned_to=$_POST['assigned']`, the `completed='_POST['completedTime']` or the `id='$_POST['ticket']`.  I think when I click "Update" it is looking at every field named "assigned"/"completedTime"/ and "ticket".  How can I ensure only one record is selected?

```
<?php require_once('../con.php'); ?>

<?php

    //query DB
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";

    $results = mysql_query($query, $con) or die (mysql_error() . mysql_error($con));
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($results);


    //Update db
    if (isset($_POST['update']))
    {       
        $update = "UPDATE table SET assigned_to=$_POST['assigned'], completed='$_POST['completedTime'] WHERE id='$_POST['ticket']'";
        mysql_query($update, $con);

        if (!mysql_query($update, $con)) 
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Report</h1>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST" accept-charset="iso-8859-1">

<hr size="1" noshade="noshade" />

<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="small">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>TicketNum</strong></td>
    <td><strong>User</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Category</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
    <td><strong>AssignedTo</strong></td>
    <td><strong>CompletedDate</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php 
    $colorarray=array('#FFFFFF','#D9ECFF');
    $colorarraysize=count($colorarray);
        if ($BRB_rowcounter++%1 == 0){ 
        if ($colorarrayindex<($colorarraysize-1)){
            $colorarrayindex++;
        }else{
            $colorarrayindex=0;
        }
    } 
    echo "$colorarray[$colorarrayindex]"; ?>">
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <td valign="top"><?php echo $row['issue_details']; ?></td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row['timestamp']; ?></td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="assigned" value ='<?php echo $row['assigned_to']; ?>'></td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="completedTime" value ='<?php echo $row['completed']; ?>'></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="ticket" value ='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)); ?>

</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php

mysql_free_result($update);

mysql_free_result($results);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry copy and paste error.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this line `$update = "UPDATE table SET assigned_to=$_POST['assigned'], completed='_POST['completedTime'] WHERE id='$_POST['ticket']'";` --- missing `$` for `completed='_POST['completedTime']`

Comment: Just use `mysqli_` with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and be done with it.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you have PHP syntax errors (you cannot use `'`-quoted array keys in a `"`-quoted string.

Comment: Such as?  I'm just learning PHP and mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
<?php
        require_once('../con.php');

            //Update db
            if (isset($_POST['update']))
            {       
                $update = "UPDATE table SET assigned_to='{$_POST['assigned']}', completed='{$_POST['completedTime']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['ticket']}'";
                $result = mysql_query($update, $con) or die ('Error' . mysql_error($con));
        }

        //query DB
            $query     = "SELECT * FROM table";
            $results   = mysql_query($query, $con) or die (mysql_error() . mysql_error($con));
            $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($results);

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Report</h1>


    <hr size="1" noshade="noshade" />
    <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="small">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>TicketNum</strong></td>
        <td><strong>User</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Category</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
        <td><strong>AssignedTo</strong></td>
        <td><strong>CompletedDate</strong></td>
      </tr>

    <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

                $colorarray     = array("#FFFFFF","#D9ECFF");
                $colorarraysize = count($colorarray);

            if ($BRB_rowcounter++%1 == 0){ 
                    if ($colorarrayindex<($colorarraysize-1)){
                            $colorarrayindex++;
                    }else{
                            $colorarrayindex=0;
                    }
                } 

            $content .= <<< END
                <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="iso-8859-1">
                <tr bgcolor="{$colorarray[$colorarrayindex]}">
                        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">{$row['id']}</td>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">{$row['username']}</td>
                        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">{$row['category']}</td>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">{$row['title']}</td>
                    <td valign="top">{$row['issue_details']}</td>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">{$row['timestamp']}</td>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="assigned" value="{$row['assigned_to']}"></td>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="completedTime" value="{$row['completed']}"></td> 
                    <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
                    </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="{$row['id']}">
                </form>
END;

            }
        echo $content;
        mysql_free_result($results);
      ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: After clicking "Update" this does the same thing as my previous code.  Text box is cleared and no value updated in the DB.

Comment: fyi there should be no space after $content .= <<< END in the same line, and no space character before and after END; in the same line.

Comment: I get an internal server 500 error unless I comment out form: $content .= <<<_END to END;

Comment: I mean $content .= <<< END this is correct. no '_' is needed.

Comment: Still getting 500 error.  I have $content(space).=(space)<<<(space)END(no space)....(no space)END;(no space).  Everything in the form is grayed out except the {$row['fieldname']}

Comment: Same.  If commented out the form comes up (no data) otherwise I get a 500 error.

Comment: please comment out the $content block and inside the while loop please write print_r($row);

Comment: print_r($row) is successful and shows the data but I'm unclear why the heredoc isn't working.  I understand what your doing I just don't understand in this situation why it isn't working.  Thanks for you help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your string interpolation syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
$update = "UPDATE table SET assigned_to='{$_POST['assigned']}', completed='{$_POST['completedTime']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['ticket']}'";
```

You need to put `{ }` around an array reference if the index contains quotes. You can also leave out the quotes:

```
$update = "UPDATE table SET assigned_to='$_POST[assigned]', completed='$_POST[completedTime] WHERE id='$_POST[ticket]'";
```

You also had some missing quotes and dollar signs, which I've fixed here.

See the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for details of string syntax.

However, this is very poor style, since it's subject to SQL injection. You should preferable use an API that supports prepared queries (PDO, mysqli); if not, assign the `$_POST` parameters to variables and call `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitize them.

Comment: I'm not entirely worried about SQL injection this is only internal use for 1 or 2 people.  I added the {} but I still don't get any update to the DB.

Comment: What is the type of `assigned_to`? If it's a string, you need quotes around the value.

Comment: It's varchar.  No errors.  After clicking "Update" it just clears the text box.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting a PHP syntax error. Check your error log.

Comment: If there's no error, it has to print something. Even if the update doesn't do anything your page prints the table header and all the other boilerplate. What does the Network tab in the browser console say, does it show a successful `200` code or an error?

Comment: After "Update" successful 200